# Deform Issue with Rig

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I am having a bit of trouble setting up this rig to the mesh. I have fiddled with the Vertex groups and weights to make the sleeve cuff not deform except inline with the sleeve but for some reason is continues to deform. The Cuff seems to deform with the hand rotation but it shouldn't. The sleeve has no vertex' in the hand deform or any of the finger bone deforms but still it deforms.

[image: Deform Issue]

Any Ideas?
These are the vertex groups for the sleeve. the Weights at this point are set to max in attempt to figure out what is going on.
[image: Sleeve]

Comment: I have been doing some testing and it only deforms like this once the elbow bends. Will keep looking for a solution

Comment: I figured it out... Apparently my Bicep vertex group had been auto-weighted to have the outside of the cuff to it. this is the problem.

Comment: you can always post an answer on your own question when you found your solution , so that future answer seekers could use it to solve their "similar" encounters.

Comment: Thanks Hawkenfox....I am new around here and didn't know how to resolve a question. it is done now.

Answer (score 1):

The vertex group for the Bicep area was for some reason also including the cuff region which is not very helpful. So there was an extra deform to the cuff that was messing things up.

Thanks